# Run-time error only when running code in changeevent

Tags: excel, vba, count, range, runtime-error

So I am importing data from a workbook to another workbook. In the workbook that will receive the data, I have a macro (see below) that should count the total amount of rows (from B13:lastrow) and add a comment with this.

I get run-time error -2147417848 (80010108)
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

When I use `Application.EnableEvents = False` I do not get these errors, however, the macro won't work either.
I guess it has something to do with the ActiveSheet I am using?

```
Sub FindTotalAmountOfRowsInColumn()
Dim startCol As String
Dim startRow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim myCol As String
Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws2 = ActiveSheet 'Preserves a reference to the active sheet as ws2
ThisWorkbook.Activate 'Makes this workbook the one that is displayed

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
startCol = "B"
startRow = 13
lastrow = ws.Range(startCol & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
'lastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastCol = ws2.UsedRange.Columns(ws2.UsedRange.Columns.count).Column


myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)


Set Rng = ws.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastrow)


ws.Range("A8").Value = "ITEMCOUNT:" & Rng.Rows.count

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Would I be correct to guess that Sheet1 is the worksheet you are catching a change event on??

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. So the file is "CIF LISTEN.xlsm", the sheet is "Sheet1". It is by the way working if I put it under BeforeSave.

Comment: `Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet`  - this is actually setting ws as type Variant   ,you must use `Dim ws as Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet`

Comment: Yea you're gonna send the code into an infinite loop doing that because you set the value of A8 which retriggers the change event.

Comment: Hi @StevenMartin my apologies for the late answer. I tried to Dim it that way and use the enableevents. Apparently, it seems like it is working, so I think the `Dim as` did the work! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an infinite loop by changing the value of A8 thus retriggering the Worksheet_Change event of Sheet1. `Application.DisableEvents = False` is a common way to address this issue and works for most cases. (More complex cases other things such as boolean triggers might be used). Based on the fact that you say nothing happens anymore I'm left to assume you never re-enabled events with `Application.DisableEvents = True`. I've tested locally to verify and achieved the effect I've described. Run the following macro to re-enable events (if they are still disabled):

```
Sub enabEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then make sure you disable events at the beginning of your method and re-enable events at the end of your method.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
//
// Your method code
//
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: It seems like it is working now using enableevents and using the other Dim As :) Thank you.